# UISplitViewController: Show masterViewController after navigation in detailViewController on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am just playing around with the new functionalities of UISplitViewController in iOS8. Now I am looking for a solution for the following problem. In my case I want to show some kind of main menu inside the masterViewController. If you choose an entry in the menu the content in the detailViewController changes. Now you could navigate inside the detail area changes. And here is my problem:

On iPads the splitViewController behaves like this: You could navigate through any number of viewControllers in the detail area. But you could still swipe in the masterViewController that contains the main menu.

But on iPhone the masterViewController is just the rootViewController of a navigationController. So when you are in the n-th level inside the detail area, you have to navigate back through all previous viewControllers to reach the main menu again.

Do you know any solution to access the main menu from any viewController in the detail areas navigation stack?

Best regards,
SlimShady

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button on nav bar or anywhere else to trigger an Unwind Segue and jump straight to the menu view controller as explained in quite a detail in this wonderful answer - [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them/15839298#15839298)